# Remove all AV entries in registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus

We had to manually uninstall AV from a bunch of PC's but it has left some stale registry entries.
Specifically we want to remove entries found under 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Security Center\Provider\Av'.

Problem is no matter what I try I am unable to delete keys here, I dont have the required permissions to delete or take ownership.

Have tried:
`Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -Class AntiVirusProduct | where { $_.displayName -notlike '*Defender*' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }`

But it does not seem to clean up that reg key.

Comment: Can you obtain the Vendor's AV Cleanup Tool.  That would be the best way, I think;

Comment: Each anti-malware suite makes specific tweaks to the system so that malware cannot easily defeat it. As @John states, each suite has its own removal tools.

Comment: @John, yes I know.. unfortunately we have many devices and wanted to script this in PowerShell. The vendor tools generally all require GUI interaction, which cant be scripted/automated. I figure if their software removal tool can remove the registry key, why cant we (permissions wise)?